# Reference for a proof of the Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

The [Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#The_Hahn.E2.80.93Mazurkiewicz_theorem) states that a space $X$ is a Peano Space if and only if $X$ is compact, connected, locally connected, and metrizable. If anybody knows a book with a proof, please let me know. Thanks.

**P.S.** (added by t.b.) A *Peano space* is a topological space which is the continuous image of the unit interval.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hocking and Young, Topology
also has a proof, theorem 3-30, page 129. Visible in Google Books.

Answer (score 11):

Read the section on Peano spaces in *[General Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486434796)* by Stephen Willard.