# "Cutting out" loops from paths

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Given a topological space $X$ and a path $p : [0, 1] \to X$ such that $p(0) \neq p(1)$, does there always exist an injective path $p' : [0,1] \to \operatorname{im}p$ such that $p'(0) = p(1)$ and $p'(1) = p(1)$? For intuitive examples of paths we could "cut out" the loops which occur in $p$, but are there pathological examples of paths in which this technique cannot be applied? Otherwise, is there a Theorem that guarantees the existence of $p'$, even for only certain "nice" classes of paths $p$?

For any $X$ that satisfies this property, any subspace of $X$ is path-connected if and only if every two points are joined by an injective path.

What about the special case where $X = \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: You want to assume $p(0) \neq p(1)$ to ensure injectivity is possible, i.e. that $p$ is not a loop. It seems to me you might be able to do some sort of inductive process where you cut out loops, but it's going to get messy if $p$ is a space-filling curve.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that into the question.

Comment: I may misunderstand the question, but I think that it is probably not true in general because there are countable, connected Hausdorff spaces. In particular, since $[0,1]$ is uncountable, there cannot be an injection into a countable space, and we require it be connected since the continuous image of a connected set is connected.

Comment: @Clayton Do you have an example of a non-trivial path-connected countable space $X$?

Comment: @JacobSchlather: A quick search returned [this page](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1953-004-03/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9.pdf), but I haven't taken the time to read it, so it might not work.

Comment: @Clayton, Yes I'm not sure about that one but spacebook says [this space](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=248&spaceID=14) is path-connected. So perhaps OP should ask the question in a nicer setting, such as Euclidean space or manifolds.

Comment: @JacobSchlather: Yes, I am prepared to ask the question in the setting of Euclidean space. I will edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155462/every-path-has-a-simple-subpath) seems to answer you question.

Comment: @MihaHabič It does... I'm unhappy though, because the intuition of "cutting out loops" suggests we should have a simple loop of the form $p'=p\circ f$ where $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is continuous, nondecreasing and fixes the endpoints. An argument based on Hahn-Mazurkiewicz does not give this, as far as I can tell. Perhaps the question can be reworded again to ask for $p'$ of the above kind... better than just closing it as a duplicate.

Comment: @5PM I'm not sure I understand what you were trying to say with $p'=p\circ f$; if $f$ is as you require, it is surjective so $p'$ would be surjective onto the image of $p$.

Comment: @MihaHabič Sorry, $f$ should not be continuous. It should be nondecreasing, fixing the endpoints, and such that $p'=p\circ f$ is a continuous simple path. The jumps of $f$ correspond to loops of $p$ being cut out.

Comment: @5PM Maybe something like $$f(t)=\max\{\sup p^{-1}[\{t\}],\sup_{s\lt t}f(s)\}$$ would work? Possibly with some padding to fix the endpoints?