# Can every two points be connected by a simple curve?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a path-connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. For $x,y\in X$, $x\neq y$, does there necessarily exist a simple curve connecting $x,y$? In other words, is there an injective continuous map $\gamma:[0,1]\to X$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$, $\gamma(1)=y$?

I could neither prove this nor find any counterexample. It is easy when $\gamma$ has finitely many self-intersections. But is there any result for the general case?

Comment: Is that $\gamma(1)=y$?

Comment: @samerivertwice Yes it was a typo. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A question about path-connected and arcwise-connected spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61868/a-question-about-path-connected-and-arcwise-connected-spaces) Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155462/every-path-has-a-simple-subpath?rq=1 and many more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) has the answer if you connect the dots. You are asking whether a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is path-connected is als arc-connected. If you use the induced topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$ any subspace will be Hausdorff and for Hausdorff spaces path-connected and arc-connected are equivalent. So the answer is yes.

Comment: This result is... really astonishing! Thanks a lot :)