# Definition simply connected in $\Bbb C$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

I recently saw a different definition for **simply connected** which I had never seen before. A connected subset $\Omega\subset\Bbb C$ is called **simply connected** if the boundary is the image of a simple closed curve. Is this equivalent to the usual definitions?

Thanks

Comment: This does not coincide with the usual definition, because the boundary of a simply connected open set of $\Bbb R^2$ could be much more complicated than a simple closed curve.

Comment: could you provide an example, reference? Thanks

Comment: Imagine an $8$-shaped area. It's interior is not simply connected, but it's boundary can be an image of a simple closed curve, like a circle, and even a continuous image of it.

Comment: But this curve would not be simple. It would self intersect.

Comment: @Mike: You may see the pictures in page 15-1 [here](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/preprints/ims90-5.pdf). Pictures $(b)$, $(c)$, $(d)$ are counter-examples. There are more pathological counter-examples, but let me leave the answer to others.

Comment: @Mike: it isn't a simple curve, but it's the *image* of a simple curve. Nevertheless, you require the set to be connected - and in my example it's not.

Answer (score 3):

> image of a simple closed curve

Interpretation 1: the word "image" refers to the fact that a curve is really a map (parametrization), and the geometric shape that we think of as a curve is the image of that map. Some people, including me, would omit the words "image of" in this case.

With this interpretation, we have the definition of a *Jordan domain*, which is a  smaller class of domains than  simply connected. For example, the slit disk $\{z:|z|<1\}\setminus [0,1]$ is a simply connected domain but is not a Jordan domain.

> image of a simple closed curve

Interpretation 2: the word "image" means continuous image. A set is a continuous image of a simple closed curve if and only if it is compact, connected, and locally connected (this follows from the [Hahn-Mazurkiewicz  Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/39584/79365). Again, we have a more restrictive definition that simple-connectedness:

- the boundary of a simply connected domain need not be compact (consider the halfplane)
- the boundary of a simply connected domain need not be locally connected. To construct an  example, remove the vertical line segments from $1/n$ to $1/n+i$, $n=1,2,\dots$ from the open quadrant $x>0,y>0$.

---

Remarks:

1. I guess the first interpretation was the intended one.
2. It is true that a connected subset of $\Omega\subset\mathbb C$ is simply connected if and only if the set $\overline{\mathbb C}\setminus \Omega $ is connected in the topology of the Riemann sphere $\overline{\mathbb C}$. In the special  case when $\Omega$ is bounded, this amounts to  $\partial \Omega$ being connected.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Yes, the first was the intended.