# Prove that $ \ A \ $ is a $ \ G_\delta \ $ subset of $ \ X \ $.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $ \ (X, d) \ $ be a metric space and let $ \  A ⊆ X \ $. Suppose that $ \  (A, d) \ $ is homeomorphic to a complete metric space $ \ (Y, d_Y ) \ $. Prove that $ \ A \ $ is a $ \  G_\delta \ $ subset of $ \ X \ $.

**Answer:**

Since $ \ (A,d ) \ $ is homeomorphic to a complete space , then $ (Y,d_Y) \ $ can be embedded into $ \ X \ $ .

Now since $ A \ $ is complete , we can write $ A=\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \ C_n \ $  , where $ C_n \ $ are closed set .

**But now can not conclude the proof** .

**please help me out**

Comment: Why is $A$ complete?

Comment: You have to prove one direction of Mazurkiewicz's theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set#Properties).

Comment: You can find a very nice proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151207/proof-of-mazurkiewicz-theorem