# Intersection of countable collection of open subsets of a complete metric space can be made complete

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space and $U$ is a countable collection of open subsets of $X$. Show that $\bigcap U$ can be endowed with a metric topologically equivalent to $d$ with respect to which $\bigcap U$ is complete.

**Attempt: Some Background:**

> **(i) Theorem:** Open subsets of a complete metric space can be made into complete metric spaces by judiciously altering the metric. Let $U$ be an open set in $X$. Define $f(x) = \dfrac {1}{dist_d(x,U^c)}$ where $dist$ refers to the distance function i.e. $\inf \{d(x,w)~|~w \in U^c \}$. Then, the metric $e:(a,b) \rightarrow d(a,b)+|f(a)-f(b)|$ converts $U$ into a complete space. Also,$d,e$ are topologically equivalent

**EDIT:** I found a solution below:[image]

I couldn't understand why $e(a,b) \le d(a,b) + |f_,m(a) - f_m(b)|$. Is it an error?

Also, is there really a need for the summation?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could considere the metric on $U$ :

$$\rho(a,b)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1\wedge e_n(a,b)}{2^n}$$

It is known as Alexandroff-Mazurkiewicz theorem : [Proof of Mazurkiewicz theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151207/proof-of-mazurkiewicz-theorem)

Comment: I have edited and added a solution image. Could you please have a look and suggest me if the solution is correct? Thanks!

Comment: and thank you for the link!

Comment: I don't know where does the inequality $e\leq d+|f_m(a)-f_m(b)|$ come from. But you can see that $d$ and $e$ are equivalent metrics showing they have the same convergent sequences.

Comment: yep got it. I have one more query though. Do you think we could have done away with the summation sign.? What specific use did it serve?